# Whether or not your action is for families is required before publishing a Google Assistant action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I was on the process of publishing my first google assitant action and after filling all the required details I am receiveing two errors.
1.Whether or not your action is for families is required
I have already checked and accepted the terms and conditions for families question. The data is saved also. Still I do not know why the error keeps popping up.
2.For en: Your sample invocations are structured incorrectly.
I have tested my invocations in the emulator and it seems to be working. And this error appears to be random. Sometimes, it does not happen  even if I just save the same details again.

Any help appreciated as I am a complete new-bie to this.

Comment: Contact support here: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Answer (score 1):

I think this was a problem from the console itself. I updated today again and it seems to be saved.